# Conditionally render a component based on selectOneMenu value

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, conditional-rendering

Is there a way to render a component based on the current value the user has selected from a selectOneMenu component?  My selectOneMenu component is populated with an enum consisting of two values, smoker and non-smoker.  If the user has smoker selected I want to render a checkbox below it which lets the user check how many they smoke a day 10, 20, 30+, etc.  I also want the opposite to work if they user has selected non-smoker i.e. the check boxes don't render/disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check the dropdown menu's value in the `rendered` attribute of the target components and update their common parent by a `<f:ajax>`. Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.item}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="one" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" />
    <f:ajax render="results" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="results">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.item eq 'one'}">
        You have selected "one".
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.item eq 'two'}">
        You have selected "two".
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.item eq 'three'}">
        You have selected "three".
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If you'd like to perform some business logic based on the selected value, use `<f:ajax listener>`.

```
<f:ajax listener="#{bean.changeItem}" render="results" />
```

```
public void changeItem() {
    someResult = someService.getByItem(item);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)
- [How to load and display dependent h:selectOneMenu on change of a h:selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505248/how-to-display-dependent-hselectonemenus-with-a-list-of-countries-and-cities/)
- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)