# SelectOneMenu depends to other selectOneMenu - Jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly

I have a Webapp with the Technologies: Wildfly, JSF, Primefaces

I have to select One Menus. The first Select One Menu loads all Warehouses and the second Select One Menu loads all Products which depends to the selected Warehouse.

I want to implemente the posibility, that i don't have necessarily choose a warehouse. I want to have the possibility that i dont select a warehouse, and logically if i dont choose a warehouse, the product Select one menu has to be disabled.

If i submit the form without a warehouse, it should be written in the database null for warehouse and also null for product.

My first attempt was to do the following entry in the select one menu of warehouse.

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="---" itemValue="#{null}" value="#{null}"/>
```

Now, i don't know how to set the value of the warehouse select one menu to null, if i haven't choose a warehouse.

```
value="#{warehouseDataActions.actualWarehouse}" --> how to set to null
```

The second Problem is, that in the Ajax of the first select one menu i have to add the Attribute immediate = true. This Attribute is only neccassary for me if i add the following line. I don't know why ?

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="---" itemValue="#{null}" value="#{null}"/>
```

So i have three questions:

1-How to set the actualWarehouse and .actualWriteservice.warehouseProduct to null ?

2. How to disable the product select one menu if i have already doesn not choose a warehouse (---) above ?
3. Why does my Ajax request in the warehouse select one menu does not function, if i add the item

   ```
   <p:selectOneMenu style="width:151px"
   value="#{warehouseDataActions.actualWarehouse}">
       <f:converter converterId="ccWarehouseConverter" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" itemValue="#{null}" value="#{null}"/>
       <f:selectItems
           value="#{warehouseDataActions.allWarehousesForProject}"
           var="warehouse"
           itemLabel="#{warehouse.warehouseName}"
           itemValue="#{warehouse}" />
       <p:ajax listener="#{warehouseProductDataActions.warehouseProductsForWarehouse}"
           update="products" />
   ```

   ```
   <p:panelGrid>
       <p:outputLabel for="products">#{texts['writeservice.product']}</p:outputLabel>
       <p:selectOneMenu id="products" style="width:151px"
           value="#{writeserviceDataActions.actualWriteservice.warehouseProduct}">
           <f:converter converterId="ccWarehouseProductConverter" />
           <f:selectItems
               value="#{warehouseProductDataActions.warehouseProductsResult}"
               var="warehouseProduct" itemLabel="#{warehouseProduct.product.productName}"
               itemValue="#{warehouseProduct}" />
       </p:selectOneMenu>
   </p:panelGrid>
   ```

Comment: 1) That's default behavior already. 2) Just use `disabled` attribute? 3) Post a MCVE. A broken converter can cause trouble with 1) and 3). The question as stated in the title doesn't cover your actual problems at all. It's already answered in a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505248/how-to-load-and-display-dependent-hselectonemenu-on-change-of-a-hselectonemenu/

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to handle the --- case in your converter
   (ccWarehouseConverter).

   ```
   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
       if (value == null || value.length() == 0 || value.equalsIgnoreCase("---")) {
           return null;
       }
       return databaseService.getWarehouseByName(value);
   }
   ```
2. To disable the selectOne

   ```
   <p:panelGrid>
     <p:outputLabel for="products">#{texts['writeservice.product']}</p:outputLabel>
     <p:selectOneMenu id="products" style="width:151px" disabled="#{empty warehouseDataActions.actualWarehouse}"
       value="#{writeserviceDataActions.actualWriteservice.warehouseProduct}">
       <f:converter converterId="ccWarehouseProductConverter" />
       <f:selectItems
           value="#{warehouseProductDataActions.warehouseProductsResult}"
           var="warehouseProduct" itemLabel="#{warehouseProduct.product.productName}"
           itemValue="#{warehouseProduct}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
   </p:panelGrid>
   ```

In order to have your ajax update working, you must encapsulate both warehouse and products in a mother panel, and you update the mother:

```
<h:panelGroup id="motherPanel" layout="block">
    <p:selectOneMenu style="width:151px" value="#{warehouseDataActions.actualWarehouse}">
        <f:converter converterId="ccWarehouseConverter" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" itemValue="#{null}" value="#{null}"/>
        <f:selectItems
        value="#{warehouseDataActions.allWarehousesForProject}"
        var="warehouse"
        itemLabel="#{warehouse.warehouseName}"
        itemValue="#{warehouse}" />
          <p:ajax listener="#{warehouseProductDataActions.warehouseProductsForWarehouse}"
        update="motherPanel" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:panelGrid>
          <p:outputLabel for="products">#{texts['writeservice.product']}</p:outputLabel>
          <p:selectOneMenu id="products" style="width:151px" disabled="#{empty warehouseDataActions.actualWarehouse}"
            value="#{writeserviceDataActions.actualWriteservice.warehouseProduct}">
            <f:converter converterId="ccWarehouseProductConverter" />
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{warehouseProductDataActions.warehouseProductsResult}"
                var="warehouseProduct" itemLabel="#{warehouseProduct.product.productName}"
                itemValue="#{warehouseProduct}" />
           </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: `---` is the label not the value.